# chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.chartContainer Not Functional?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, nvd3.js

I have a page that contains multiple graphs made ​​with NVD- chart.js . the graphs are placed in a dashboard , so each part of the dashboard contains a graph. This dashboard contains two line charts. The problem is that the tooltip of the second line-chart is badly placed in the left, so it's far from its line-chart.I tried to use this code to change the position of the tooltip by changing his container but there is no change:

```
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.chartContainer(d3.select('#chart_ligne svg'));
```

Any one have an idea how to use chartContainer ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, with floating charts. After fiddling around, I just turned off the interactive guidelines. With this, I was able to contain the tooltips inside their respective container.

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
  .useInteractiveGuideline(false)
  .showLegend(true)
```

Downside is you have to target specific points to be able to show the tooltip...